# Azure IP Blacklisted

Tags: azure, blacklist

Am hosted on Windows Azure and the IP provided as the A record is blacklisted in several spam alert groups. This is because of some other URL's that seem to share the same IP and is affected with malware. Am worried this could affect credibility of my website in the eyes of users as well as search engines.

These are the questions I had:
Is there a way to refresh my IP and get a new one on Azure? If it is, how can it be done without down time?

Comment: I think the better question is, why does it matter? Are you hosting Exchange from an Azure VM? Why? That's not a good spot for hosting mail. You might want to rethink your solution.

Comment: Not exchange, it is a website (http://check-pnr-status.in/). It is getting blocked by some filtering sites and proxies stating it is a Spam/Malicious URL. And checking why that happens led me to this problem with IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using an IaaS VM? If yes, simply Shutdown the VM (or all the VMs in the Hosted Service if you have more than one) with the Deallocated option and Start the VM again. You will get a new IP.

Comment: It is not the Web Role (compute) option or VHD option, it is the "Website" option that they provide where I just mention a data-center location and scale. Restarting in this case restarts only the App Pool and that doesn't change the IP.

Comment: In that case you are limited to the IP address provided by Azure. You may open a support ticket to make them aware of the blacklist and they would be able to either change the IP or have the IP removed from the blacklist.

Comment: Can't believe MS doesn't monitor their IP's for such blacklists and auto-correct, considering they hand out the same IP for so many sites (hundreds, I guess).

Comment: Microsoft is now proactively blacklisting azure compute ip ranges:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2016/04/04/sending-e-mail-from-azure-compute-resource-to-external-domains